# Filter a table using COUNT SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, count

I am new to SQL. I have written the code below but am getting stuck with the COUNT function. I want to only display the ClientIDs that have 2 or more ServiceIDs on the Service table. I tried doing a nested select within the join on the Service table originally and was getting error messages. Now with the code below, I am getting an error

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

I am trying to achieve the following. THANK YOU!

| client Id | Service ID | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 | 4 |

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    O.OrgName,
    Referral.ClientID, 
    Client.FirstName, 
    Client.LastName, 
    P.ProviderName AS 'School',
    E.ProgramID,
    LI.ListLabel AS 'Reason',
    Race.ListLabel AS 'Race/Ethnicity',
    Gender.ListLabel AS 'Sex/Gender',
    [ServiceId],
    (SELECT COUNT([ServiceID])
     GROUP BY Referral.ClientID
     HAVING COUNT([ServiceID]) >= 2) AS 'Number of Supports'
FROM 
    ProviderReferral Referral
JOIN 
    Provider P ON ReferFromProviderID = P.EntityID
JOIN 
    ProviderReferralExt ON Referral.ProviderReferralID = ProviderReferralExt.ProviderReferralID
INNER JOIN 
    MultiSelectValue MSV ON MSV.ContextID = Referral.ProviderReferralID 
                         AND MSV.ContextTypeID = 87 
                         AND MSV.ListID = 1000001179
INNER JOIN 
    Client ON Referral.ClientID = Client.EntityID
INNER JOIN 
    EnrollmentMember ON client.EntityID = EnrollmentMember.ClientID
INNER JOIN 
    Enrollment E ON EnrollmentMember.EnrollmentID = E.EnrollmentID 
                 AND E.X_CMNonCM = 1
INNER JOIN 
    ListItem LI ON LI.ListValue = MSV.ListValue 
                AND LI.ListID = 1000001179
INNER JOIN 
    ListItem Race ON Race.ListValue = client.Race 
                  AND Race.ListID = 1000000068
INNER JOIN 
    ListItem Gender ON Gender.ListValue = Client.Gender 
                    AND Gender.ListID = 1
INNER JOIN 
    Service ON E.EnrollmentID = Service.EnrollmentID -- the supports table
JOIN 
    Organization O ON o.EntityID = p.OrganizationID
WHERE 
    P.OrganizationID = 33847
    AND E.ProgramID = 1325 
    AND referral.DeletedDate = '9999-12-31' 
    AND o.DeletedDate = '9999-12-31' 
    AND enrollmentmember.DeletedDate = '9999-12-31'
ORDER BY
    referral.ClientID, client.FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `count` as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select ...
       ...
       Count([ServiceID]) over (partition by referral.clientid) as cnt
From ...
     ...
) t where cnt > 2;
```

Please note `order by` should be last clause in your query. Use it accordingly.

Based on the request in the comment, Adding the code into your original query as follows:

```
select * from
(select Referral.ClientID, 
       Client.FirstName, 
       Client.LastName, 
       P.ProviderName as School,
       E.ProgramID,
       LI.ListLabel as Reason,
       Race.ListLabel as "Race/Ethnicity",
       Gender.ListLabel as "Sex/Gender",
       [ServiceId],
       Count([ServiceID]) over (partition by referral.clientid) as cnt -- this -- added open parenthesis before partition
FROM ProviderReferral Referral
    JOIN Provider P on ReferFromProviderID=P.EntityID
    JOIN ProviderReferralExt on Referral.ProviderReferralID=ProviderReferralExt.ProviderReferralID
    INNER JOIN MultiSelectValue MSV on MSV.ContextID = Referral.ProviderReferralID AND 
      MSV.ContextTypeID=87 AND MSV.ListID=1000001179
    INNER JOIN Client on Referral.ClientID=Client.EntityID
    INNER JOIN EnrollmentMember on client.EntityID=EnrollmentMember.ClientID
    INNER JOIN Enrollment E on EnrollmentMember.EnrollmentID=E.EnrollmentID and E.X_CMNonCM=1
    INNER JOIN ListItem LI on LI.ListValue = MSV.ListValue and LI.ListID = 1000001179
    INNER JOIN ListItem Race on Race.ListValue=client.Race and Race.ListID=1000000068
    INNER JOIN ListItem Gender on Gender.ListValue=Client.Gender and Gender.ListID=1
    INNER JOIN Service on E.EnrollmentID=Service.EnrollmentID -- the supports table
    JOIN Organization O on o.EntityID =p.OrganizationID
Where P.OrganizationID=33847
and E.ProgramID=1325 
and referral.DeletedDate = '9999-12-31' and o.DeletedDate='9999-12-31' 
and enrollmentmember.DeletedDate='9999-12-31') t
where cnt > 2 -- this
order by ClientID, FirstName
```

Comment: Can you clarify how I incorporate this into my script? Where does this go exactly? @Popeye

Comment: I am gtting Incorrect syntax near 'partition'. Here is the code I used `count([ServiceID]) over partition by referral.ClientID) as cnt` @popeye

Comment: I realized the syntax error, your 2nd edit was missing an open ( before partition. BUT now I am getting this error message... "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified." @popeye

Comment: Update - I modified code to say `as t` instead of just `t` and that worked but NOW the order by has  syntax error. @popeye

Comment: I am just going to remove the order by for now - it seems to work with out it. Thank you!

Comment: Cool.. keep it up!!